# Can't we upload a mp3 file to Office 365 video channel/ Stream app?

Tags: office365, codec

I tired to upload an mp3 file in Office 365 video/stream but getting error message like file format is not supported.

But when checked the support file link - [Audio codec supported](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-formats-that-work-in-Office-365-Video-dd1af01c-fd8e-4640-b17b-93ee02b9b817) contains .mp3 file for Office 365 video. Why it is not allowing me to upload an mp3 file?

Answer (score 1):

Audio codec is not the same thing as the file format. For example you can have a video file encoded with video codec H.264 and audio codec of MP3 with file format .mp4.
Microsoft Stream (aka Office 365 Video) only supports formats listed in *Supported video file formats section*. In fact mp3 is not a video file format.

The solution might be to change file extension from mp3 to mp4. Then you should be able to upload the file to Microsoft Stream service.

[Here](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/faq/codecs-and-formats) you can read more about the differences between codecs and formats.